# I'm trying to prove this language is not context-free: {a^x b^y c^z | where x=z and x<y}

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

So far i've tried with making x = z = p and y = 2*p, but it seems that if I place vxy to represent all b's then I can't get a contradiction.

Comment: Try $y = p + 1$

Answer (score 1):

The pumping lemma for context-free languages says the following: 
For every context-free-language $L$ there exists a constant $p$ such that for every word $s \in L$ of length at least $p$, we can write $s = uvwxy$ and:

- $|vx| \ge 1$
- $|vwx| \le p$
- $uv^nwx^ny \in L$ for $n \ge 0$

To prove that $L = \{a^xb^yc^z: x < y \land x = z \}$ is not context-free we will do the following: 
Assume language $L$ i context-free and let $p$ be the constant from the pumping lemma. 
Take the word $s = a^pb^{p+1}c^p$, which is clearly in $L$, and express it as $s = uvwxy$ as is stated in the lemma. 
We know that $|uvw| \le p$ so $v$ consists only of $a$'s. 
Denote $s_n = uv^nwx^ny$ 
Now consider the possible cases:

1. If either $v$ or $x$ contain more than one letter, than $s_2$ will not be of the form $a^*b^*c^*$, so we know that $v$ and $x$ will consist of at most one letter.
2. If $v$ is empty and $x$ consists of $b$'s then $s_0$ will not have more $a$'s than $b$'s. If $x$ consists of $c$'s then $s_2$ will have more $c$'s than $a$'s.
3. If both $v$ and $x$ are non-empty then if $v$ consists of $a$'s and $x$ of $b$'s then we in $s_2$ we will have more $a$'s than $c$'s. If $v$ consists of $a$'s and $x$ of $c$'s than for large enough $m$ in $s_m$ we will have more $a$'s than $b$'s. If $v$ consists of $b$'s and $x$ of $c$'s then in $s_2$ we will have more $c$'s than $a$'s.
4. If $v$ and $x$ consist of the same letter (i.e $w$ is empty) then following the same type of reasoning we will also reach a contradiction.

Thus we have reached a contradiction for every possible case and so $L$ is not context-free.

Comment: You don't have the pumping lemma for context free languages quite right. The second condition should be $|vwx| \leq p$, so your case analysis comes out wrong. There's nothing that forces $v$ to be near the start of the string, so you can't assume it's only $a$s. However, you can state three similar cases: $vx$ contains some $a$s and hence no $c$s, only $b$s, or some $c$s and hence no $a$s. The first and third give the $x \neq z$ contradiction, and the second (with $s_{0}$) gives the $x = y$ contradiction.

Comment: You're right got that mixed up, will try to fix it in a minute :)

Comment: Should be ok now :)